# regular expression to split C56STOP

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

```
([A-Z,_])([0-9]+)([A-Z,*,_,])
```

I have been using the above expression to split strings such as "C54G" into "C", "54", "G" or "C54_" into "C", "54", "_"

I have run into a situation where I now need an expression that will split "C54STOP" into "C", "54", "STOP" but only if "STOP" exists. in the dataset, there will also be, for example, "C54G"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `([A-Z_])([0-9]+)([A-Z*_]*)`?

Comment: yes this is the solution....that simple...shows what a novice I am. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `*` quantifier (*zero or more repetitions*) at the end:

```
([A-Z_])([0-9]+)([A-Z*_]*)
                        ^
```

Also note the commas insider character classes are treated as literal commas, they do not work ass alternation operators, and thus must be removed.